# ListView with subitems. (Android)

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, simpleadapter

I need to show in a listview a query result to the DB. I'm returning the query 2 values ​​("cod", "value"). I thought of using a SimpleAdapter to solve the problem, but it did not work.

this is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.techcharacteristic);

    PopulateTechCharacteristicList populateList = new PopulateTechCharacteristicList(
            this);

    populateList.execute();

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.techcharacteristic_rows,
            new String[] {"cod", "value"}, new int[] {
                    R.id.techCharacteristic, R.id.techCharacteristicName });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public class PopulateTechCharacteristicList extends
        AsyncTask<Integer, String, Integer> {

    ProgressDialog progress;
    Context context;

    public PopulateTechCharacteristicList(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(TechCharacteristicList.this,
                getResources().getString(R.string.Wait), getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.LoadingOperations));
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... paramss) {

        ArrayList<TechCharacteristic> arrayTechChar = new ArrayList<TechCharacteristic>();
        TechCharacteristicWSQueries techCharWSQueries = new TechCharacteristicWSQueries();

        try {

            arrayTechChar = techCharWSQueries
                    .selectTechCharacteristicByAsset("ARCH-0026");


            HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String,              

            for(TechCharacteristic strAux : arrayTechChar)
            {
                temp.put("cod", strAux.getTechCharacteristic() + " - " + strAux.getTechCharacteristicName());
                temp.put("value", strAux.getTechCharacteristicValue());
                list.add(temp);
            }


        } catch (QueryException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        if(result == 1)
            progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

On account of being utlizando the same codes ("cod", "value") to include values ​​in the HashMap, my listView is always showing the last item inserted. But in my statement SimpleAdapter'm using hard coded ("cod", "value") and whenever I put any value other than ("cod", "value") in the HashMap, the listView carries empty.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In that `for` loop in the `doInBackground` method you need to make a **new** `HashMap` **each time** and not use the same map object.

Comment: initialize adapter and setListAdapter in postexecute() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On account of being utlizando the same codes ("cod", "value") to
>   include values ​​in the HashMap, my listView is always showing the
>   last item inserted.

As you are creating `HashMap` object out of `for loop`, and adding values to that object only in the for loop,hence the previous values get erased and you get only last values.

To solve this you need to create the `HashMap` object in `for loop` corresponding to each row.

**Try**

```
        HashMap<String, String> temp = null; 

        for(TechCharacteristic strAux : arrayTechChar)
        {
            temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
            temp.put("cod", strAux.getTechCharacteristic() + " - " + strAux.getTechCharacteristicName());
            temp.put("value", strAux.getTechCharacteristicValue());
            list.add(temp);
        }
```